# Which one is best for chat Apps in Android. FCM or WebSockets?

Tags: android, websocket, google-cloud-messaging, chat, java-websocket

I am going to develop Chat applications for android. There are two methods FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) and WebSockets. Which one is easy to develop and which will be higher in performance in realtime?. I want to implement images, Videos, Audios sharing features too. So Please suggest me good method to develop.

Comment: For real time chat you should go with Firebase

Comment: If i use Firebase for my business. Google will charge me ?

Comment: According to your data usage they can charge..but as start up they provide free stuff Ref: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a complete chat project](https://github.com/AleBarreto/FirebaseAndroidChat)

You should fill it with your firebase credentials to get it working, the source code is simple to understand and you can easily update the features. This project already has some features built with it.

Comment: Can i able to manage chats from web side?

Comment: You can view all the structure from the console, so you can edit the json , thereby you can customize in the way you wish it should be.

Comment: Thanks manoj. The messages which i sent will be secured(encrypt and decrypt) ?

Comment: No, the messages won't be encrypted. For that you should consider using xmpp or some other protocol's.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provided you to realtime database and simple data in real time database. I think you should be better using FCM.